# Wireguard VPN Outbound and Inbound

Tags: ubuntu, ip, routing, tunnel, wireguard

I am trying to setup a Wireguard tunnel so that A uses the IP of B for **outbound and inbound** traffic (like a proxy, not a std VPN config). Both boxes are Ubuntu 16.04.

A is eth0, behind a router with NAT and on DMZ, with IP A

B has two public IPs: a main one (ens3 aka B1) and a secondary one (ens3:0 aka B2). The secondary one should be dedicated to the WG tunnel.

**WG on A:**

`Interface
Address = 10.200.1.2/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 50614
FwMark = 0xca6c
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[Peer]
PublicKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <B2>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 10`

**WG on B:**

`[Interface]
Address = 10.200.1.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
[Peer]
PublicKey = zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
AllowedIPs = 10.200.1.0/24
Endpoint = A:50614`

**Route on A:**

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0`

**Route on B:**

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         B1.B1.B1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
B2.B2.B2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
B1.B1.B1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
169.254.169.254 B1.B1.B1.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens3`

**Which route do I need to add so that every outbound packet from A goes out via B2 and every packet inbound to B2 gets sent to A?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a lot of help from the Wireguard community, and here's what works.

A (client)

```
[Interface]
Address = B2/32
PrivateKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = B2:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 10
```

B (server)

```
[Interface]
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AllowedIPs = B2/32
```

Don't forget about the usual steps (on B)

- open 51820/udp in the firewall
- set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

If the wg0 interface on B is showing constantly growing error count, you might want to disable DMZ for A or restrict inbound on ports which are in use at B2 that also might have traffic via A to the WG interface. This might be the case if you are running peer based services.